# Should I throw PHP 7's Error classes in a library?

Tags: php, exception, php-7

I have open-sourced a [math library for PHP](https://github.com/brick/math), which defines its [own hierarchy of exceptions](https://github.com/brick/math/tree/0.5.3/src/Exception):

- [ArithmeticException](https://github.com/brick/math/blob/0.5.3/src/Exception/ArithmeticException.php)

  - [DivisionByZeroException](https://github.com/brick/math/blob/0.5.3/src/Exception/DivisionByZeroException.php)
  - [NumberFormatException](https://github.com/brick/math/blob/0.5.3/src/Exception/NumberFormatException.php)
  - [RoundingNecessaryException](https://github.com/brick/math/blob/0.5.3/src/Exception/RoundingNecessaryException.php)

Now that PHP 7 has landed, I realize that some exceptions feel a bit redundant with the new `Error` classes introduced:

- [ArithmeticError](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.arithmeticerror.php)
- [DivisionByZeroError](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php)

Let's forget PHP 5 for a moment and assume that the library only targets PHP 7.

- Should I throw `ArithmeticError` and drop my `ArithmeticException`?
- Similarly, should I throw `DivisionByZeroError` and drop `DivisionByZeroException`?
- Should `RoundingNecessaryException` and `NumberFormatException` extend `ArithmeticError`?
- In this case, should they be called `RoundingNecessaryError` and `NumberFormatError`?

At first glance, it seems weird to redeclare exceptions that have a native equivalent in the language.

At the same time, and although nothing prevents userland code from throwing an `Error`, I feel like these classes were designed to be thrown by PHP itself, and that userland libraries are better off throwing `Exception` and not `Error`.

Is there a consensus on the subject?

Comment: To the person voting to close: voting to close a question on the basis of "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." is counter-productive, and kinda "shooting the messenger". Even if we were to decide that answers that are opinion-based (what sort of answers *aren't*?) are a bad thing, then condemn the *answer*, not the question. Try to be collaborative, eh? Judge a situation on its overall merit, not a commandment in a rule book. And if you don't have anything useful to add, simply jog on.

Comment: TBH, I knew this question would be targeted by "primarily opinion-based" compulsive voters. I tried to do my best to ask for a consensus, not an opinion. Maybe the guys who created the [Throwable RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throwable-interface) wrote something on the subject. Maybe there is an half-official answer to this. Who knows. I needed to ask anyway!

Comment: PHP Error exceptions are intended to be thrown in situations where a *programmer* error occurred. Any Error thrown should be undeniably linkable to an actual bug in your code. If your use of Error or its subclasses matches this constraint, you may use them in your code. (This also implies that you should never catch these exceptions except in your top-level handler or very unusual situations. If your exceptions are supposed to be caught, then Error is not right for you.)

Comment: @NikiC It's a good reflection to have on my exceptions. I guess there might be situations where it makes sense to catch a DivisionByZero or a RoundingNecessary exception, even more a NumberFormatException, especially when dealing with user input.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have Stack Overflow moderatory literalists voting to close this because answers are going to be "primarily opinion based". For some reason SO thinks this is bad or different from other answers which in general are also opinion based given questions seldom have a single answer.

This is a reasonable question.

If we were to limit the scope of the question to simply DivisionByZeroError and Arithmetic error, then I think you should follow PHP's standardisation here, and leverage those errors. This moves you closer inline with the principle of least astonishment in that it makes your code in-step with expectations one would have with one's own code it one - for example - divides by zero. So this is a good thing (I think one can objectively say that).

However - now this is subjective - I would not be actively *throwing* those errors, I'd simply be letting my code error. IE: don't trap the situation and re-throw the same error, just let the code error. It simplifies your code (objective), and has the same end result (objective). So this ties into your instinct that one oughtn't throw these built-in errors. But only because it's not necessary: PHP will deal with that for you. I would not *intrinsically* say one should not actively throw these errors, but I s'pose the situation in which it's legitimate (or even necessary) would be an unorthodox one, so it might beg the question if it's the right Error to throw.

As for non-specifically-catered for situations like RoundingNecessaryException vs RoundingNecessaryError... I think it makes sense to upgrade them to errors. I cannot find the reference in the docs just now (someone else might be able to, and update this?), but they state that Errors are for programming errors which a dev will need to change code to fix; and exception is just for exceptional runtime behaviour. Or words to that effect. So if one wants to make your method that might throw a RoundingNecessaryError work, one needs to do the necessary rounding. This is a code-time consideration, so an Error makes sense. I think this is slightly subjective as there's no cut and dried single answer for this, but I think the rationale is a fairly objectively sound one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About not *actively* throwing the `DivisionByZeroError`, this is not possible as I'm not using `intdiv()` under the hood, but different calculator implementations based on GMP, BCMath, or even plain PHP. I need to harmonize exceptions so that this stays an implementation detail.

Comment: About `Error`s being for programming errors, this could make sense, but I think it's just adding some confusion, as PHP already had classes for this in its [exception hierarchy](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php): for example, [LogicException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php) "represents error in the program logic. This kind of exception should lead directly to a fix in your code". So for similar causes, we now have 2 plausible throwables: `Error` and `LogicException`. That's why I thought that, maybe, `Error` was really supposed to be thrown by PHP only?

Comment: There's def some overlap there. I can only conjecturise that LogicException predates the revision to error handling that PHP7 brought in. Also LogicException is somewhat broader (or just different) from a DivisionByZeroError. But I cannot speak to that really. PHP's approach to error handling has always baffled me slightly. It seems to have a very odd approach to the whole thing.